NativePHP + javascript event listening
Im having trouble with NativePHP and JS. As stated in the NativePHP docs

NativePHP injects a window.Native object into every window.

However
Native.on("Native\\Laravel\\Events\\Windows\\WindowFocused", (payload, event) => {
      alert("it works");
});

results in Uncaught ReferenceError: Native is not defined - clearly nothing is injected in Window. Can anyone help me, what am I missing...? Thank you.

Are you sure the JavaScript library is loading? Does window.Native work?

It is clearly not loading, but as the doc states it, NativePHP should inject it.

Is there a <script> tag in the HTML that should load it? If not, I think you must be initializing the library in PHP wrong. Since you haven't posted any code, it's impossible to tell what you're doing wrong.

Which versions of the packages are you running? As they're in alpha, the documentation only represents the current state of the latest release. If you're not running the latest versions, you may not have all the features as documented. Try running composer require nativephp/electron -W to get the latest version
